C++: Windbg Extensions - Better Way to Evaluate Argument Definitions as PCSTR args
When writing a Windbg Extension (using DbgEng.h), it's possible to use _In_opt_ PCSTR args to accept arguments from the Windbg command line; however, this is passed as a full string.
Example:
HRESULT CALLBACK doStuff(_In_ PDEBUG_CLIENT4 Client, _In_opt_ PCSTR args)
This means/infers things like getopt() are not viable paths to obtain the arguments, because they're not passed on Windbg initialisation - but on the command execution within Windbg.
After a few weeks of researching, I was able to find this code block (in pure C), which will evaluate whether the PCSTR contains the expected values we would want from the arguments to the command (shout-out to Ryan Ries for it). The only issue, to me, is that there's no way (seemingly) to evaluate whether the expected string is in the "correct place".
So, for example, if I wanted to allow -q -s someModule!someMethod, then the validation from Ryan's example would work for -q someModule!someMethod -s; which isn't - inherently - a problem, but I would like to validate if the input is expected (with the arguments and values in the correct place) before continuing processing on within the debugger extension.
I'm suspecting that splitting the string on space character might be the way to go but I wonder if that is the recommended/preferred way to do input validation on args passed-in as a PCSTR because then we have to assume indexes that might not be, necessarily, true. So, for example, -q -s someModule!someMethod would have a different last index than -s someModule!someMethod.
Is there a standard/preferred/"correct" way to evaluate the arguments passed-in via PCSTR? If so, I couldn't find any examples of this or "best practices" to use.
If not, what would be the "best way" to handle conditionals of some arguments not being supplied and trying to index where the someModule!someMethod would be?

Something like... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw ...?

I believe the method you referenced would give me the original command line used to init Windbg and not the argument-line passed by the debugger extension execution.
In Windbg, the command would look like !doStuff -q -s someModule!someMethod

Try checking the engextcpp.cpp in samples it has code that parses the arguments  passed

Are those the samples that only come from the SDK? I'll try to download the SDK and look there; I've been dev'ing against the "new" Windbg (from the MSFT store) and I don't think it comes with any samples.


Are those the samples that only come from the SDK?

probably yes I have not checked or used the store package 

i have it here
C:\>dir /s /b  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc\*.cpp"
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc\engextcpp.cpp

the relevent part are as follows
C:\>pss Parse "c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc\engextcpp.cpp"
c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\inc\engextcpp.cpp
259:ExtCommandDesc::ParseDirective(_In_ PSTR Scan)
354:ExtCommandDesc::ParseArgDesc(void)
357:    // Parse the argument description.
397:            Scan = ParseDirective(++Scan);
809:            ParseArgDesc();
2436:            ParseArgs(Desc, Args);
3004:ExtExtension::ParseArgs(_In_ ExtCommandDesc* Desc,

it is documented here
Parsing Extension Arguments
